# What causes "Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:: nested asn1 error" when building a public key in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, certificate, rsa, apple-push-notifications

When building a public key using the OpenSSL::PKey::RSA module by passing it a .pem file, what is the cause for a response:

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:: nested asn1 error
from /Users/Matt/projects/placepop/lib/apn.rb:48:in `initialize'
from /Users/Matt/projects/placepop/lib/apn.rb:48:in `new'
from /Users/Matt/projects/placepop/lib/apn.rb:48:in `open'
from (irb):1
```

Here is the source:

```
cert = File.join(rails_root, 'config', 'apns', 'sandbox-cert.pem')
APN_CONFIG = { :delivery => { 
                              :host => 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', 
                              :cert => cert,
                              :passphrase => "",
                              :port => 2195 },
               :feedback => {  
                              :host => 'feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com',
                              :port => 2196,
                              :passphrase => "",
                              :cert => cert} }


options = APN_CONFIG[:delivery].merge(options)
cert = File.read(options[:cert])
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ctx.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(cert, options[:passphrase])
ctx.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(cert)

sock = TCPSocket.new(options[:host], options[:port])
ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock, ctx)
ssl.sync = true
ssl.connect
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A pem file is not a public key, it is a base64-encoded X509 certificate that contains, among its many fields, a public key. I don't know Ruby, or the OpenSSL ruby module, but I would look for some function that reads in PEM files and outputs an X509 certificate, then another function to extract the public key from the certificate.

Comment: You're correct. The problem was from the way that the pem file was exported from the certificate. The private key was not included.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. What exactly did you do wrong when exporting the certificate? My .pem file contains my private key at the bottom of the file.

Comment: I am having the same issue...i pass only my private key !

Comment: This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39115092/1180523. Store the PEM contents as a single line (using `\n`) in an ENV variable, and then make sure to use the `.gsub` suggestion in the link.

Comment: My (silly) problem was, even though I was feeding it the private key, there was whitespace on the left of the lines of the private key, because it had been indented. Left-justifying every line of the key string got rid of this error.

Answer (score 40):

If you are using `dotenv` for instance, you have to surround the value with `"` and have `\n` for newlines.

```
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICW  ... UcuUtU0eIl\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Comment: My problem is exactly this. Thank you!

Comment: also wrapped the key in `"` and it works for me now, thank you!

Answer (score 39):

I've got the same problem and it had a different cause. Now guess what :)

...

The damn password was wrong :(
Searched 3 days for that "solution". Could have been a "Sorry dude, that's the wrong password!" instead of "nested asn1 error" imho but anyways, maybe this will help somebody.

Comment: Someone should poke upstream with sturdy stick about this too... *escapes*

Comment: I confirm, had the same issue and a wrong password was causing it. Thanks to your post, I was able to fix it. The error message is definitely not accurate.

Comment: @2called-chaos as of 2018 I can't thank you enough haha thinking that the pw had typos was the last thing I thought about when checking some code that wasn't working, that error message couldn't be more useless

Comment: You da man!  I don't know I messed up the password.  But recreating the keys fixed this.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem too, but for me I wasn't creating a pem file for my id_rsa.pub file in the first place.  For me I needed to create a pem file out of my existing public key:

```
ssh-keygen -f testing_rsa.pub  -e -m pem > pem
```

Then I copied that OpenSSL string into my test file where it was being used.  It looked like this in the end for me.

```
@pub_key = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBCgKCAQEAoxi2V0bSKqAqUtoQHxWkOPnErCS541r6/MOSHmKOd6VSNHoBbnas\nZRQSDUTbffB6C++DbmBCOHmvzYORD0ZWYgyMcgbYJD48Z2fe0nm+WMYN5u8DPnTP\nvf8b/rJBxGF0dsaoFAWlB81tTnKFCxAbCSgfmQt+Vd4qupGZ5gGu9uoKlaPjmYuA\nIxIjUMcu3dov7PQ+PZIvdkM0fiz8YIl8zo+iWWyI2s6/XLoZJ4bYs2YJHZDf6biU\nsZhs8xqh/F6qlcRt3Ta25KMa0TB9zE3HHmqA/EJHFubWFRCrQqpboB0+nwCbmZUl\nhaxA79FRvYtORvFAoncoFD4tq3rGXcUQQwIDAQAB\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
.
.
.
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(@pub_key)
```

After that the method stopped throwing that error.

Comment: Thanks! I was exactly in the same case.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your `.pem` files are in this format.

**public_key_file.pem:**

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

// Your public key goes here

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

**private_key_file.pem:**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

// Your private key goes here

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Just adding the link to the LTI 1.3 reference implementation which was giving me this error until I followed your advice to leave in the BEGIN and END comments: https://lti-ri.imsglobal.org/

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new()` wants the file **contents** and not the file path. Thus, using something like this worked:

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read "./spec/support/keys/server.key")
```

The OP was already doing this, but hopefully this will help someone. Because it assumes it's file contents and not a file path, even if you supply an invalid path you won't be warned.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Webrick in my tests and trying to instantiate my private key with the wrong class led me to that error message:

```
    SSLCertificate: OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open(MOCK_CERT).read),
```

But **this** worked:

```
    SSLCertificate: OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open(MOCK_CERT).read),
```

*Facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while using **dotenv** with rails.
The issue was not with respect to **dotenv** gem.
It was assigning correct value as confirmed by printing **ENV['PRIVATE_KEY']**

Issue occurred because i was loading this value in **YAML** file with **ERB** processing and that led to removal of **\n** character hence making the value invalid

The workaround that i found was to use **ENV['PRIVATE_KEY']** directly and not via **YAML**

Answer (score 1):

if none of the above answers worked, it might be because of an incorrect algorithm. newer public keys are made using `ECDSA` algorithm instead of `RSA`, so `OpenSSL::PKey::EC` class should be used instead.

You can verify the key's algorithm using this [online tool](https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp). it detects the algorithm and provides useful information about the key.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the function expected a private key while there was a certificate stored in some variable. Exchanging the input with a private key fixed the error.