# Rails can't read certificate information from environment due to nested asn1 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've got some certificate files, namely a .key file which says:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
IEpAIBAAKCAQEAwAwxt4edIh3UuK8r5
....blablabla..................
QSNoquaasdsaKDybrezemVqCxsQjg==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So it's a RSA Private Key.

I used to load them from files like so:

```
@private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(private_key_file))
```

But since I am using Heroku, I intend to have my certificates saved as their values in environment variables.

So I've pasted them in my .env file

```
COMPANY_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEpAIBAAKC.....\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Yeah, I switched the `\n` for explicits `\\n` based on [Multi-line config variables in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942600/multi-line-config-variables-in-heroku). So now my code looks like this:

```
@private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(ENV['COMPANY_KEY'])
```

And if I run it from the console I get the object built. But if I try to run it from the web server (Puma 3.4.0 over Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.2.3) it fails miserably saying: ***`Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:: nested asn1 error`*** when trying to run that same line.

If I use the debug console I get that the read file looks like 
`"Line 1\\nLine3\\nLinea3"` and so on...

I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the file format, but I'm all out of ideas and maybe you could help if you had a problem like mine.

Comment: Please create a test private key, and then post it. While your doing so, take a look at [How to generate RSA private key using openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30493975/608639). Notice the difference between a ***public key*** and ***subject public key info*** with resect to the pre-encapsulation header (***`-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`*** versus ***`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`***). The same holds for private keys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it... mixing it all up!

So the file, for example company.key looks like

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE RSA KEY ----
Mumbojumbomummbojumbo
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----
```

So I switched it to a one liner, making explicit \n in the string (so its a real \n)

```
COMPANY_KEY=""-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA+ztKEj\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

Don't forget the last \n in the file.

Now, the last part, in the place where I used to do

```
@private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(private_key_file))
```

Now I do

```
@private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(ENV['COMPANY_KEY'].gsub("\\n", "\n"))
```

And now works like a charm! No public certificates, every piece of info in environment variables.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Adding the `.gsub("\\n", "\n")` was the piece I needed to add. (btw, you should accept your answer as the correct one)

Answer (score 4):

Save yourself some trouble and store only the certificate or key body in the environment variable. No need to put in newline characters.

```
SECRET = <<-SECRET
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
#{ENV['SECRET_KEY']}
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
SECRET

CERTIFICATE = <<-CERT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#{ENV['CERT']}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
CERT
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but this method assumes the ENV exists. I was asking how to save the value into the environment in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> I switched the `\n` for explicits `\\n` based on [Multi-line config variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6942600/52317) in Heroku.
>
> ...
>   If I use the debug console I get that the read file looks like  `"Line 1\\nLine3\\nLinea3"` ...

You problem should be here. The post you are linking is not suggesting to double escape your new lines, it is suggesting to wrap your multi-line text into "double quotes". In bash, it would allow to enter multi-line text at the terminal. The post also suggests to do it an in much easier way:

```
heroku config:add MASISA_KEY ="$(cat your_private_key.pem)"
```

Comment: Maybe that could help me while uploading the key to Heroku, but I am trying to test my code on my development machine. So what I find need is to try out that the certificate is correctly loaded in my .env file.