# Unable to Generate RSA Public key in ruby

Tags: ruby, rsa

I am unable to create a object of OpenSSL::PKey::RSA class for a public key in string format. The following is my code:

```
public_key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAttI6ImgD74PhHWVqnrqSOmStboplyL02DB3/nc2iyDdYLzXoBIQN+NPMBPlsZlEKuKjsg5Ycfp6VjcmncM3CH9MGIr+Lmbj1HZmO/jJGJ84RPhzYOiZuElzs3seIcOtOa3BpFeqRsXJlrf1IVBKVU3erka5ACLVyrsjmp/VXMx5QjPD0qXARMGb6rDewTkyg3pGz07Y7rZgXkTl54ase+XaPegOankxdEQhVjPdrk7eSlIQS5Ni7FAcSyTOtYoPgiP7W0PolOMHvpFg96CHjc8V8xDsFdh0wbHd49WcKxiJMIfL65VUIW5aob9fw05a5FczyASa0iNtRiICy/QnCqQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new public_key
```

I am getting the following error:

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error
```

I am using ruby version ruby 2.3.7. Any body can tell me what is wrong with string or function.?

I have try adding \n solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293608/what-causes-neither-pub-key-nor-priv-key-nested-asn1-error-when-building-a-p)

```
public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIB\nIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAttI6ImgD74PhHWVqnrqSOmStboplyL02DB3/nc2iyDdYLzXoBIQN+NPMBPlsZlEKuKjsg5Ycfp6VjcmncM3CH9MGIr+Lmbj1HZmO/jJGJ84RPhzYOiZuElzs3seIcOtOa3BpFeqRsXJlrf1IVBKVU3erka5ACLVyrsjmp/VXMx5QjPD0qXARMGb6rDewTkyg3pGz07Y7rZgXkTl54ase+XaPegOankxdEQhVjPdrk7eSlIQS5Ni7FAcSyTOtYoPgiP7W0PolOMHvpFg96CHjc8V8xDsFdh0wbHd49WcKxiJMIfL65VUIW5aob9fw05a5FczyASa0iNtRiICy/QnCqQIDA\nQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

but I am getting same error

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error
```

Add \n on different places

```
public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAttI6ImgD74PhHWVqnrqSOmStboplyL02DB3/nc2iyDdYLzXoBIQN+NPMBPlsZlEKuKjsg5Ycfp6VjcmncM3CH9MGIr+Lmbj1HZmO/jJGJ84RPhzYOiZuElzs3seIcOtOa3BpFeqRsXJlrf1IVBKVU3erka5ACLVyrsjmp/VXMx5QjPD0qXARMGb6rDewTkyg3pGz07Y7rZgXkTl54ase+XaPegOankxdEQhVjPdrk7eSlIQS5Ni7FAcSyTOtYoPgiP7W0PolOMHvpFg96CHjc8V8xDsFdh0wbHd49WcKxiJMIfL65VUIW5aob9fw05a5FczyASa0iNtRiICy/QnCqQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAttI6ImgD74PhHWVqnrqSOmStboplyL02DB3/nc2iyDdYLzXoBIQN+NPMBPlsZlEKuKjsg5Ycfp6VjcmncM3CH9MGIr+Lmbj1HZmO/jJGJ84RPhzYOiZuElzs3seIcOtOa3BpFeqRsXJlrf1IVBKVU3erka5ACLVyrsjmp/VXMx5QjPD0qXARMGb6rDewTkyg3pGz07Y7rZgXkTl54ase+XaPegOankxdEQhVjPdrk7eSlIQS5Ni7FAcSyTOtYoPgiP7W0PolOMHvpFg96CHjc8V8xDsFdh0wbHd49WcKxiJMIfL65VUIW5aob9fw05a5FczyASa0iNtRiICy/QnCqQIDA\nQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

Is generating same error message.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes "Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:: nested asn1 error" when building a public key in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293608/what-causes-neither-pub-key-nor-priv-key-nested-asn1-error-when-building-a-p)

Comment: Probably the 3rd answer on the page that anothermh linked. Wrapping your string in double quotes and adding a `\n` (literally) after the `MII` and before the `QAB` (at beginning and end of your string) worked in a console.

Comment: @JayDorsey please share your string because I am getting same error even after adding \n in the string. For further investigation I have added the string in my question thanks.

Comment: You placed them wrongly. Like this: `"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMII...QAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"`

Comment: @Amadan I am still getting same error. Thanks

Comment: @user1969191 Added as an answer because of character limits

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new class was unable to created the new object because their is some issue with the public string key.

I find out the key is invalid in the following way:

In ruby console/irb

```
puts public_key.to_s.gsub('\n', "\n")
```

Save the output in a file with name public_key.txt and run the following command on ubuntu terminal

```
openssl pkey -inform PEM -pubin -in public_key.txt -noout &> /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    echo "this was definitely not a public key in PEM format"
    exit 1
fi
```

If key is invalid the above script will print

> this was definitely not a public key in PEM format

And will print nothing if key is valid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't generate any errors for me (your original string yielded the same error you noted).

```
require 'openssl'
public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAttI6ImgD74PhHWVqnrqSOmStboplyL02DB3/nc2iyDdYLzXoBIQN+NPMBPlsZlEKuKjsg5Ycfp6VjcmncM3CH9MGIr+Lmbj1HZmO/jJGJ84RPhzYOiZuElzs3seIcOtOa3BpFeqRsXJlrf1IVBKVU3erka5ACLVyrsjmp/VXMx5QjPD0qXARMGb6rDewTkyg3pGz07Y7rZgXkTl54ase+XaPegOankxdEQhVjPdrk7eSlIQS5Ni7FAcSyTOtYoPgiP7W0PolOMHvpFg96CHjc8V8xDsFdh0wbHd49WcKxiJMIfL65VUIW5aob9fw05a5FczyASa0iNtRiICy/QnCqQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"8xDsFdh0wbHd49WcKxiJMIfL65VUIW5aob9fw05a5FczyASa0iNtRiICy/QnCqQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new public_key
```

That returns `#<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x00007fa78b9b6ee8>` rather than an error. If I remove the `\n` I can reproduce the error you noted.

Ruby 2.5.3, macOS, using openssl installed via homebrew.