# How to use a TLS client certificate with a RubyGems registry?

Tags: ruby, ssl, bundler

I have an internal RubyGems registry from which I want to download some Gems. The registry is protected and requires a valid TLS Client Certificate.

I am able to reach the registry in Chrome (imported the certificate bundle into Chrome), but I am not able to do it with Bundler.

The [documentation](https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-config.1.html) says `ssl_client_cert` has to be:

> Path to a designated file containing a X.509 client certificate and key in PEM format.

I get the following error when using the certificate provided:

```
either PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error
```

How do I assemble my certificate and key?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293608/what-causes-neither-pub-key-nor-priv-key-nested-asn1-error-when-building-a-p) answer make sense?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon it makes sense, but it doesn't help me. I have a keypair and a certificate over the public key, that I need to use for the connection. I'm not sure what needs to be included in the only file to be imported, nor how to assemble all the existing files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to assemble the files:

```sh
# Concatenate the key and the certificate
openssl rsa -in key.pem > ruby-bundler-cert.pem 
openssl x509 -in cert.pem >> ruby-bundler-cert.pem
# Tell bundler to use the file 
bundle config ssl_client_cert ~/certs/ruby-bundler-cert.pem
```

Did you think this was enough? No! You also need to specify this value somewhere else: in your `~/.gemrc` file.

```
:ssl_client_cert: "/full/path/to/the/certs/ruby-bundler-cert.pem"
```

Hope this will help other people.